# add score functionality to game

Tags: javascript, html

i currently have this for my code.

https://codepen.io/selectivesuccess/pen/zYZRQVL

i want to add a score functionality to this.

i have already created things like
`var score = 0`, but i don't know how to further go on.

as you can see, the score div is already at the top of the page, but i don't know how to create a score functionality. i would appreciate any help. thanks

```
      <h3> 
        Your Score:<span id="yourscore"></span> out of 5
      </h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: To make this easier and cleaner I would use Vue.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add this line inside the guess() function:

```
document.getElementById("yourscore").textContent = txt == data.db[data.question].answer ? score+1 : score;
```

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @Evan you should select an answer as the accepted one.

Comment: sorry i am new to this how do i select?

Comment: near my answer (under number of upvotes) there's a check icon :)

Comment: There ya go :D.

Answer (score 1):

Update your `guess()` method with the method I have defined below. Also add these two methods which increment the score count and update score in the DOM.

```js
function updateScore()
{
  document.getElementById('yourscore').innerHTML = score;
}

function validateAnswer(txt)
{
  if(txt===data.db[data.question].answer){
    score++;
    return "correct";
  }
  return "wrong";
}

function guess()
{
  const txt = document.getElementById("guess").value.trim().toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = validateAnswer(txt);
  updateScore();
}
```

I have cloned the codepen and updated the solution here: https://codepen.io/sushrut111/pen/poeaXEa

Comment: THANK YOUUUUUUUU THAT WAS HELPFUL I WISH I COULD UPVOTE BUT I DON'T HAVE ENOUGH REPUTATION

Answer (score -1):

You can change the content of your "yourscore" span with: document.querySelector("#yourscore").textContent = score;

querySelector let's you pick elements like you do in css files:
(# for ids)
(. for classes)